# PHP socket_read() and socket_recv() Woes

Tags: java, php, sockets, networking

**Edit**: I've solved my own problem and fixed the code below to reflect those changes in case anyone runs into the same difficulties. This code will work for a PHP client and java server connection.

I know the forums are peppered with these questions...however, I have tried nearly everything else for over eight hours and am at my wit's end. I am trying to send a string from a java Socket to a PHP Socket. I'm a PHP socket newbie so hopefully someone can diagnose my problem rather easily... Here is the PHP code:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//connection to NetworkService in app to manage incoming request
$addr = 'your server address';
$port = 1740;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
socket_connect($socket, $addr, $port);

//"\r\n" is very important as it signifies to the server
// that this is the end of the transmission 
$request = "message to send \r\n";

//no flags needed circa php 5.2
$sent = socket_sendto($socket, $request, strlen($request), 0 , $addr, $port);

if($sent !== FALSE){
    $message = '';
    $next = ''; 

    //loop through to continue appending until everything has been read
    while($next = socket_read($socket, 4096)){
        $message .= $next;
    }
    echo $message;
} else{
    echo "Failed.";
}

socket_close($socket);
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Java Code:

```
public class TestServer{
    public static void main(String argv[0]) throws Exception{
        String in; String out = "Hello PHP\r\n";
        ServerSocket inSock = new ServerSocket(1740);

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Now accepting connections");
            Socket outSock = inSock.accept();
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(outSock.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter sender = new PrintWriter(outSock.getOutputStream());
            in = bReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + in);
            dWriter.print(out);
            System.out.println("Sent: " + out);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is not with the first send (from PHP to JAVA) but with the second one (the response) which just hangs. The Java code runs completely so I know the problem has to do with the socket_read() or socket_recv() functions. I have tried to sleep() and tried a method using socket_setnoblock() (though perhaps incorrectly).  As you can see by my "OPTION:" comments, I have tried a few different methods here as well but to no avail. What could I be missing? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 4):

According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php), `socket_recv()` will return an integer, which is the number of bytes received.

The problem is the `false !==`, which you shouldn't use here (since `socket_recv()` returns an integer). This condition should be enough:

```
while(0 != socket_recv($socket, $out, 1024)){
      if($out != null)
        $fullResult .= $out;
    };
```

You may be interrested by [`socket_last_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-last-error.php).

Comment: Thanks for the second pair of eyes! I fixed that portion but am still having the same problem. The updated code has been edited into the original post.

Comment: Using socket_last_error() is a good tip. However, since the script hangs right now at the socket_recv() line (I think), the socket_last_error() method is never called...

Answer (score 2):

A bit late (coming across this looking for another issue.

In your PHP, try setting the socket to non-blocking, and then loop until you get the desired "end of message" response (that you force Java to send, in case below is newline). You could alos use socket_read (as that ends on a newline) but the following if code I used below.

```
socket_set_nonblock ($socket);
$receiveStartTime = microtime(true);
$response = '';
$retval = false;
while(microtime(true) - $receiveStartTime < 0.5) {
    $n = @socket_recv($socket, $dataIn, 1024, 0);  // Assume max return value is 1024 bytes.
    if ($n) {
        $response .= $dataIn;
    }
    if (strpos($dataIn, "\n") !== false) {
        @socket_clear_error ( $socket );
        $response = str_replace("\n", '', $response);
        break;
    }
}
if (socket_last_error($socket) > 0) {
    $this->lastErrorNum = socket_last_error($socket);
    $this->lastErrorMsg = 'Unable to read from socket: ' . socket_strerror($this->lastErrorNum);
    @socket_clear_error ( $socket );
} else {
    $retval = $response;
}
```